# hook_block_alter()

Tags: hooks, ajax, users

I am altering `user-login-block` block with `hook_block_alter()`.
Some fields are being added and Submit Button is replaced by my custom buttom with ajax call attached to it.

Now in ajax callback after some logic, if the conditions are made, user should be logged in and `user-login-block` should be replaced with `user-menu`. It is working so far.

1. My goal is to show `user-menu` after succefull login in ajax callback
2. User that was logged in in ajax callback should be logged in after any on page click after `user-menu` was displayed

Problem is that I have different sessions: on page and in ajax call.
Is there any way to render menu for user with no permissions to see this menu?

`hook_block_alter()`:

```
function customregister_form_USER_LOGIN_BLOCK_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['name']['#required'] = FALSE;
  $form['pass']['#required'] = FALSE;
  unset($form['actions']);
  unset($form['#validate']);
  $form['email'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Email'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#required' => TRUE
  );
 $form['first_name'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Vorname'),
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#default_value' => '',
   '#required' => TRUE
 );
 $form['last_name'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Name'),
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#default_value' => '',
   '#required' => TRUE
 );
 $form['birthday'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Birthday'),
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#default_value' => '',
   '#required' => FALSE
 );
 $form['gender'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Gender'),
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#default_value' => '',
   '#required' => TRUE
 );
 $form['register_url'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Register Url'),
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#default_value' => '',
   '#required' => FALSE
 );

 $form['facebook']['fb_login'] = array(
   '#type' => 'markup',
   '#markup' => '<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();" size="large" show_faces="false" auto_logout_link="false"></fb:login-button>'
 );
 $form['submit'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Absenden'),
   '#type' => 'button',
   '#value' => 'Save',
   '#ajax' => array(
     'event' => 'click',
     'callback' => 'customregister_fb_callback',
     'wrapper' => 'block-user-login',
     'method' => 'replace',
     'effect' => 'fade'
   )
  );
}
```

Ajax callback:

```
function customregister_fb_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $action = null;
  $fb_mail = $form_state['values']['email'];

  // global $user;
  $user = user_load_by_mail($fb_mail);
  $register_url = $form_state['values']['register_url'];
  if ($user) {
    if($fb_mail){
      global $user;
      $user = user_load_by_mail($fb_mail);
      $account = array('uid' => $user->uid); //existing uid
      user_login_finalize();
      $user_menu = _customregister_user_menu();
      $action = '<div id="ajax-response">fb_login'.$user_menu.'</div>';
    }else if (isset($form_state['values']['name']) && isset($form_state['values']['name']) && $uid=user_authenticate($form_state['values']['name'], $form_state['values']['pass'])) {
      global $user;
      $user = user_load($uid);
      $menu = menu_navigation_links('user-menu');
      $output =  theme('links__user_menu', array('links' => $menu));
      drupal_session_regenerate();
      $action = '<div id="ajax-response">'.$uid.' </div>';
    } else{
     $action = '<div id="ajax-response">Not Logged in  <pre>'.print_r($form_state, true).'</pre></div>';
    }

  }
  return $action;
}
```

The logic in Ajax Callback is in Development and should not be considered here.

So far I can see possibilities as follow:

1. Share session for ajax and first request (no idea how)
2. Render menu with Drupal Api and overcome permissions for not logged in user (no idea how)
3. Render menu manually streight from DB (already done)

Could anyone Help?